# keep only function names when obfuscation for proguard

Tags: java, proguard

I use proguard for obfuscation. How can I keep only function names while obfuscation. class names must be obfuscated but function names.

if I use,

```
-keep class * {
     void somefunction();
}
```

and it keeps function of somefunction, but it doesnt change classes names.

But, I want to change classes names but somefunction

Comment: ...Out of curiosity, why would you possibly want this behavior?

Comment: I have jni project (android ndk). and I use some java function in c++. I can get class of object, so class names can be obfuscate. I must know functions names, so function names cannot be obfuscate

Comment: Okay, so class names _can_ be obfuscated, but if function names are staying consistent, then what's the point?  Your code won't be that obfuscated anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `-keepclassmembers` or `-keepclassmembernames`.

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Usage > [Overview of Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview)

Comment: the link is died

Answer (score 0):

With Proguard, you can use `-keepclassmembernames`

In JNI, the class name is part of name of the function name in the native environment.

If you rename the class, you will get the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

You must keep both the class name and the member function name.